# c# формат ToString("##:##:##")

Tags: c#

Всем привет, помогите пожалуйста. Visual Studio c# жалуется, что "входная строка имела не правильный формат"

```
label2.Text = mp3Reader.TotalTime.ToString("##:##:##");
```

NAudio
На вход приходит время но с миллисекундами, 00:00:00.0000
Надо обрезать все после точки.
Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Какой тип имеет свойство TotalTime?

Comment: Не знаю, не могу найти NAudio

Comment: public virtual System.TimeSpan TotalTime { get; }

Comment: Достаточно нажать F12 в студии чтобы перейти к определению класса и там посмотреть

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем, решил, а почему бы и нет. В общем, разобрался. Может, кому-то в дальнейшем поможет.

```
label2.Text = mp3Reader.TotalTime.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
```